# Haskell Lambda Case Or

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to write Lambdacase with logical operators:

```
\case
 (MyDataConstructor1) || (MyDataConstructor2) -> MyFunc1
 ohterwise -> MyFunc2
```

Comment: `case` doesn't work via boolean logic. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: There have been some `MultiCase` proposals: https://wiki.haskell.org/MultiCase

Comment: @AJFarmar it kinda does though. In F# it is legal to list multiple patterns on a branch like `match x with A | B -> y; C | D -> z`. Haskell doesn't allow this, but I wouldn't go as far as "this doesn't make sense".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Haskell `case` expressions don't admit multiple patterns on one branch, unlike in some other ML languages like OCaml or F#. You have to list the two patterns separately:

```
\case
    MyDataConstructor1 -> MyFunc1
    MyDataConstructor2 -> MyFunc1
    _ -> MyFunc2
```

Also note the underscore in the last case: you shouldn't use `otherwise` in that position, because `otherwise` is not a special language construct, but merely [an alias for `True`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.21/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:otherwise) from the standard Prelude. So while your example would technically work (by binding the value that is being cased to the name `otherwise`), it wouldn't be very clear to the reader, and besides would produce a name shadowing warning.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly you need to use Lambdacase..? You may do it straightforward like

```
\val -> case val == MDC1 || val == MDC2 of
          True -> "wow"
          _    -> "duh"
```

or by using the `bool` function from Data.Bool

```
\val -> bool "duh" "wow" (val == MDC1 || val == MDC2)
```

then even without lambda like

```
bool "duh" "wow" . ((||) <$> (MDC1 ==) <*> (MDC2 ==))
```